# How to print fullcalendar with given date range including all events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

How can someone print fullcalendar or export fullcalendar in PDF or Excel format?

For example:

Input:

Start Date: 01 Jan 2020

End Date: 31 Dec 2020

On click of button it will get all of the events between given date ranges and populate it to the [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/)

There will be something like...

1. 26th January 2020 which will have an event - Australia Day
2. 14th February 2020 which will have an event - Valentines day
3. ...
4. ...
5. 25th December 2020 which will have an event - X-Mas Day

As you can see there will be multiple events in different months and what I am looking for is printing or exporting this fullcalendar in a single page with all 12 number of months.

Your response will help many.

Comment: you want 1) an actual calendar layout with all days shown, and events shown on the days where they occur, or 2) just a list of events? It's a bit unclear, based on your description and your sample of the events.

Comment: (BTW, version 2 is very achievable - just use a "list" view with a suitable visible range / duration. The user can open that, then click Print in their browser and they should be able to "print" to PDF. If you want an Excel export then better to do that by fetching the event data direct from the server. FullCalendar doesn't need to have any involvement in a data-driven procedure like that.)

Comment: First option actual calendar layout

Comment: version 1 is much less achievable. I think you'd need a) some JavaScript to automatically change the month view from one month to another until you'd covered all years, and then b) some more JavaScript within that which would, for each month, convert the currently displayed HTML/CSS into pdf format in-memory - probably there's some sort of library which can do it. You'd have to concatenate together all the data from each captured month into one PDF document. Exporting this visual layout to Excel would make no sense really as far as I can make out, so not sure why you asked for that.)

Comment: (if you only wanted one month of data at a time in your PDF, it would be much easier - just ask the user to press Print and then save as PDF). The reason it's hard for 12 months is that fullCalendar doesn't have a built in "full-year" layout. TBH if it's just read-only like this it might actually be easier to generate your own HTML table.

Comment: Yea I know that with single month its easy, But for all I am thinking a different solution to make a whole new calendar with jQuery and PHP and then simply HTML to PDF. But before that I would like to know if someone already did it or not.

Comment: Well I don't know if they did, maybe someone will answer. I certainly didn't create anything like it personally. As I've described above, it's not a straightforward task, so I think it makes it less likely that there's a ready-made solution out there somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below sample code by editing , hope it helps

```php
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-9");
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1254");
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=x-mac-turkish");

$today = date("d-m-Y");

// Defines the name of the export file "codelution-export.xls" 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$today-BOOK.xls");

$date = '2020-05-01';

//get end date of month
$end = '2020-05-' . date('t', strtotime($date));


include("../../DATABASE.php");
?>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>PERSONAL</td>

    <?php
      while(strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end)){
        $day_num = date('d', strtotime($date));
        $day_name = date('l', strtotime($date));
        $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
        echo "<td>$day_num <br/> $day_name</td>";
      }
    ?>
  </tr>

  <?php
    //get end date of month
    $hsql=mysql_query("select * from XXXUSER"); 
    while($hyaz=mysql_fetch_array($hsql)){
      $firstname=$hyaz["firstname"];
      $kullanicidi=$hyaz["id"];
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>$firstname</td>";
      $fromdate = '2020-06-01';
      $todate = '2020-06-' . date('t', strtotime($fromdate));

      while(strtotime($fromdate) <= strtotime($todate)) {
        $geneltarih = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fromdate));
        $fromdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day",strtotime($fromdate)));
        $xxxsql = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from XXXSCHEDULE where kaynakcodu='$kullanicidi' and start_event='$geneltarih'")); 
        $title = $xxxsql["title"];
        echo " <td>$title</td>";
      }

      echo "</tr>";
    }
  ?>
</table>
```